# avoid R loop and parallelize with snow

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, snow

I have a large loop that will take too long (~100 days). I'm hoping to speed it up with the snow library, but I'm not great with apply statements. This is only part of the loop, but if I can figure this part out, the rest should be straightforward. I'm ok with a bunch of apply statements or loops, but one apply statement using a function to get object 'p' would be ideal.

Original data

```
dim(m1)   == x x    # x >>> 0
dim(m2)   == y x    # y >>> 0, y > x, y > x-10
dim(mout) == x x    
thresh    == x-10   #specific to my data, actual number probably unimportant
len(v1)   == y      #each element is a random integer, min==1, max==thresh 
len(v2)   == y      #each element is a random integer, min==1, max==thresh
```

Original loop

```
p <- rep(NA,y)
for (k in 1:y){
    mout <- m1 * matrix(m2[k,],x,x)
    mout <- mout/sum(mout)

    if (v1[k] < thresh + 1){
        if(v2[k] < thresh + 1){
            p[k] <- out[v1[k],v2[k]]
        }
        if(v2[k] > thresh){
            p[k] <-  sum(mout[v1[k],(thresh+1):x])
        }
    }

    #do stuff with object 'p'
}
```

Comment: The `apply` class of statements are generally no more efficient than a well constructed for loop, they're just cleaner to write and useful when doing things at the command prompt. Could you create a self-contained set of simulated data to test the code that you really want to optimize? It's difficult to tell what is your bottleneck, and what can be vectorized. Vectorization is where the large performance gains will be over your for loop implementation.

Comment: How could I do this with library snow to parallelize the loop? I'd still need some apply functions, which I haven't quite wrapped my head around.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(snow)
dostuff <- function(k){
    #contents of for-loop
    mout <- m1 * matrix(m2[k,],x,x)
    mout <- mout/sum(mout)

    if (v1[k] < thresh + 1){
        if(v2[k] < thresh + 1){
            p <- out[v1[k],v2[k]]
        }
        if(v2[k] > thresh){
            p <-  sum(mout[v1[k],(thresh+1):x])
        }
    }

    #etc etc

    return(list(p,
                other_vars))
}

exports = c('m1',
            'm2',
            'thresh',
            'v1',
            'x' ,
            'v2')
cl = makeSOCKcluster(4)
clusterExport(cl,exports)

loop <- as.array(1:y)
out <- parApply(cl,loop,1,dostuff)

p <- rep(NA,y)
for(k in 1:y){
    p[k]          <- out[[k]][[1]]
    other_vars[k] <- out[[k]][[2]]
}
```