# how to use snow with r loop to parallelize

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, snow

I have a large loop that will take too long (~100 days). I'm hoping to speed it up with the snow library, but I'm not great with apply statements. This is only part of the loop, but if I can figure this part out, the rest should be straightforward. I'm ok with a bunch of apply statements or loops, but one apply statement using a function to get object 'p' would be ideal.

Original data

```
dim(m1)   == x x    # x >>> 0
dim(m2)   == y x    # y >>> 0, y > x, y > x-10
dim(mout) == x x    
thresh    == x-10   #specific to my data, actual number probably unimportant
len(v1)   == y      #each element is a random integer, min==1, max==thresh 
len(v2)   == y      #each element is a random integer, min==1, max==thresh
```

Original loop

```
p <- rep(NA,y)
for (k in 1:y){
    mout <- m1 * matrix(m2[k,],x,x)
    mout <- mout/sum(mout)

    if (v1[k] < thresh + 1){
        if(v2[k] < thresh + 1){
            p[k] <- out[v1[k],v2[k]]
        }
        if(v2[k] > thresh){
            p[k] <-  sum(mout[v1[k],(thresh+1):x])
        }
    }

    #do stuff with object 'p'
}
```

Comment: If you really want to stick with a `for` loop, look into the `foreach` package. `snow` and `parallel` support parallel versions of selected *apply functions.

Comment: This really needs a **small** reproducible example as mentioned [at your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554521/avoid-r-loop-and-parallelize-with-snow#comment76099692_44554521) to, hopefully, generate useful answers